# Geotagged tweets and Twitter API

Tags: coordinates, api, web-gis, twitter

When I do a timeline query using the Twitter API,

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=MyTwitterName
```

the geographic component of the reply looks like this:

`<geo><georss:point>49.13786075 -122.85811069</georss:point></geo>`

`<coordinates><georss:point>49.13786075 -122.85811069</georss:point></coordinates>`

Does anyone know the difference between the geo and coordinates tags? I did look in the Twitter docs but couldn't see anything. Should it always have both, or is one preferred to another?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, in older versions of the API, `geo` returns latitude,longitude and `coordinates` returned longitude,latitude. But since switching to georss, those should be the same consistently. [This question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3128655/understanding-twitter-streaming-api-geo-information) has some background about the different names.

Comment: Thanks - and thanks for formatting the question properly ;-)